# C Segmentation Fault problem

Tags: c

Let me start by saying that I've been programming in Java and C# for the last 5 years or so, so my C skills are very rusty.

I'm getting a segmentation fault, and I'm not quite sure why. 
Using gdb, I was able to find the line causing the fault, but I'm not sure what the problem is. Please help :)

I read in a integer value from a file, it's a number of seconds. Say I read save that value into char token[100]...

```
time_type sim_time;
char *s;
unsigned long time_sim;
s = token;
time_sim = strtoul(s,0,10);
int_to_time(time_sim, &sim_time);

Add_Event(eventId, agentId, &sim_time);
```

time_type is a struct, it has a bunch of fields. 
here's the declaration of int_to_time:

```
void int_to_time(unsigned long, struct time_type*);
```

now here's the declaration of Add_Event:

```
void  Add_Event(int, int, struct time_type*);
```

The call to int_to_time goes fine, but the next call to Add_Event gives a segmentation fault for sim_time. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. I tried not to include unnecessary code, but if I didn't include enough, please let me know.

Comment: if `time_type` is a struct, how are you doing `time_sim = strtoul(s,0,10);`?

Comment: Does Add_Event segfault when accessing time_type fields?

Comment: @Seth `time_sim` and `sim_time` are different vars.

Comment: Is it a typo that `sim_time` is declared as `time_type` and not `struct time_type`? Does the segfault happen *within* the source code for Add_Event or just at that line? What happens when you replace that function call with `printf("%d %d %p\n", eventID, agentID, &sim_time);`?

Comment: Have you tried cutting out lines 2-5 and doing `int_to_time(60, &sim_time);`? Can you simplify `Add_Event` and still get the error?

Comment: Seriously. Who is it that keeps upvoting all these low-qual questions within mins of posting? It's really starting to get on my nerves.

Comment: Seth, time_sim is an unsigned long.

Comment: Seth, time_sim is an unsigned long.

Tomalak, thanks for the very useful and insightful comment. Really no one should ask a question that's too simple for you, I'm sorry I upset you. 


Beta, it's not a system time of any kind, it's just a number... 

    struct time_type
    {
 /** Number of seconds in simulation time. */
 unsigned long  seconds;

 /** Number of nanoseconds in simulation time. */
 unsigned long  nanosec;
    };
    typedef struct time_type time_type;

Comment: @Tomalak, the question isn't actually that simple because there's nothing visibly wrong with the code. At least, nothing I can see. Either I'm an idiot or there's something a little more subtle at play here. John A, code for Add_Event would probably help.

Comment: Thanks for the response Max, I haven't had a chance to look back at this particular project, I will try to figure out what the problem is and I'll post what I find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library your `time_type` and `int_to_time` are coming from, but I would look at its docs and see if you need to initialize a `time_type` in some way before using it as the destination of `int_to_time` or something like that. The code isn't blatantly wrong on its face, but it's hard to tell without seeing more code.